# Creating a Custom Workflow Task for SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, content-type, workflow-tasks-list

I am trying to create a custom task workflow using a site content type. I read an article where I was instructed to create a Site Content Type and set the parent as "Workflow Task (SharePoint 2013)" (List category).

Once I have that, modify and add new site columns, I assign the site content type to my individual custom lists and modify their columns.

I am seeing several issues:

1. Cannot view or modify the Default Display Form view.
2. When I click to add an attachment, the field shows up at the very
   bottom of the form which you have to scroll down to.

Are there any resources, or is anyone familiar with this issue that could offer any advice?

I would really like to still be able to use the Workflow Task process, but not if it will still cause these issues. Thanks!